# How do I get the first object's property which is color? How do we basically deal with an array of objects in JavaScript or Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the array that I have but I have no Idea how to access the first object's individual properties.

```
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": "minivan",
    "registration": new Date('2017-01-03'),
    "capacity": 7
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": "station wagon",
    "registration": new Date('2018-03-03'),
    "capacity": 5
  }]
```

Comment: `cars[0].color`

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(cars[0].color)
>>> "purple"
```

Try the MDN js docs to learn the basics
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript